# How to make value from one step available to other steps in cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber, page-object-gem

In my scenarios the first step or two set data that I need to use in other steps. The steps look something like this:

```
Given I add 5 apples
And I add 3 bananas
```

I need to save the fruit type and quantity for each so that I can verify a few things like pricing, subtotal, total, etc. in later steps. Initially I used instance variables since the scenarios were simple. They only included one fruit type and quantity. However as the scenarios include more fruit types and quantity I need to figure out how to save this to make this available to later steps. My step when we only used one fruit and quantity per scenario was this:

```
Given(/^I add (\d+) "([^\"]*)"$/) do |quantity, type|
  @fruit = {}
  @fruit = [type => quantity]
  #rest of code here
end
```

What is the best way to change this to allow it to continue to work?

Comment: you may be using cucumber for the wrong thing if you need this level of granularity and specificity pervading through your tests

Comment: what type of tool would you recommend?

Comment: Could you provide a practical/actual cucumber step that you need to address.  For instance, how many things that you want to make it available to later steps?

Comment: replace `@fruit = {}` with the line: `@fruit ||= {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make `@fruit` a hash, where the keys are the fruit types and the values are the quanity of each fruit. For example,

```
@fruit = {:apples => 5, :bananas => 3}
```

Would represent 5 apples and 3 bananas.

You can easily do this with your Cucumber step. Note that I renamed `@fruit` to `@basket` for clarity.

```
Given(/^I add (\d+) "([^\"]*)"$/) do |quantity, type|
  @basket ||= {}
  @basket[type] = quantity
  #rest of code here
end
```

If you want to do something where more of the same fruit type is added, eg:

```
Given I add 5 apples
And I add 3 apples
```

The above step would only keep the last quantity - ie there would only be 3 apples in the basket. You could change the step to sum the quantities so that you end up with 8 apples:

```
Given(/^I add (\d+) "([^\"]*)"$/) do |quantity, type|
  add_fruit = {type => quantity}
  @basket ||= {}
  @basket = @basket.merge(add_fruit){ |key, oldval, newval|  oldval + newval }
  #rest of code here
end
```

Your other code would of course need to be adjusted to account for the hash containing multiple fruit types.

Comment: Thanks Justin. Would I be able to initialize the @basket in a module or base page? Or does it have to be done in the step?

Comment: Yes, you could. However, I am not sure that it would make sense or be beneficial.